# Como fazer uma query de um relacionamento polimórfico em Rails 3/4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eu tenho uma tabela `jobs` e uma tabela `activities`. Um Job pode ter várias Activities. O relacionamento é polimorfico.

Tabelas:

```
job         activities
----------- -------------
id          id
...         target_id
            target_type
            ...
```

Classes dos modelos:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :activities, :as => :target, :dependent => :delete_all
  # ...
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
  # ...
end
```

O estado de um dado Job é igual ao estado da última Activity criada para o Job.

```
Job +-> Activity 1 - state: new        |
    +-> Activity 2 - state: submitted  +--> Estado desse Job é approved
    `-> Activity 3 - state: approved   |
```

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer uma query que traga todos os Jobs que estejam num determinado estado, considerando ActiveRecord do Rails 3/4?

Também me ocorreu agora uma ideia de, ao invés de fazer essa query, usar algo como os "counter caches" fazem e desnormalizar esse relacionamento. Eu criaria um campo redundate chamado `state` no modelo `Job` e manteria os dois em sincronismo usando um `after_create` no modelo `Activity`. Algo assim:

```
after_create :update_state

def update_state
  target.update_attribute(state: self.state) if target.respond_to?(:state)
end
```

Seria essa uma alternativa viável?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você está procurando alternativas a query, você poderia utilizar a gem https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Com o controle de estados e a possibilidade de executar métodos nas mudanças de um estado para outro você resumiria tudo para algo do tipo

```
  after_transition :to => :submitted do |transition|
    # Sincroniza ou executa o que você quiser após o job ir para o estado submitted
  end

  # Atividade muda o estado de acordo com a máquina que você definiu, sem
  # você se preocupar em dizer o estado que a atividade deve ir
  activity.next
```

Apesar de parecer mais díficil utilizar uma máquina de estados, no seu caso diminuiria a complexidade do sistema como um todo.

Answer (score 0):

Queres trazer todos os jobs approved de um objeto?

```rails
Job.first.activities.where(state:'approved')
```

Queres trazer todos as activities que estão relacionadas a jobs?

```rails
Job.joins(:activities).where(activities:{state:'approved')
```

- porém recomendo criar um scope para isso

o proprio active record vai preparar o `sql` com a `query` `targetable_id = x e targetable_type = 'Job'`

---

também recomendo usar state_machine